# Appending results from multiple instances into the same array in Python

Tags: python, oop

This is a dummy code. I've to create multiple instances of the inner class and append them into a list. Then for each instance, I invoke a method in the inner class that returns something. How can I collect the return values from all instances into a single list or a NumPy array? I couldn't figure out working with multiple instances. Any help is appreciated.

```
import numpy as np

class Outer:
    def __init__(self, num_users):
        self.user_list = np.zeros(num_users)
        self.users = []
        
    def add(self, height):
        self.users.append(self.Height(height))
        
    def collect(self):
        if len(self.users) <= len(self.user_list):
            for user in self.users:
                h = user.func_height()
                np.append(self.user_list, h)
            print(self.user_list)
        
    class Height:
        def __init__(self, height):
            self.height = height
        
        def func_height(self):
            # print(self.height)
            return self.height
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    instance = Outer(4)
    instance.add(170)
    instance.add(177)
    instance.add(180)
    instance.add(185)
    instance.collect()
```

I want to add heights from all instances into the `self.user_list` list.

Comment: What's the problem? Also don't use nested classes. They're worse than useless if you're expecting Java behavior.

Comment: The numpy array doesn’t update and always shows zeros as originally declared.

Comment: `np.append` isn't _inplace_ as, for example, `list.append`. So you must do `self.user_list = np.append(self.user_list, h)`.

Comment: ```self.user_list = np.append(self.user_list, h)``` worked. Thank you